# Why can't I render multiple cards using map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to render multiple cards by pulling data from the API. But the return is an array, I don't understand why the map is not working.

```
  
const CharacterCard = () => {

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev)
}

  const characters = useRequestData([], `${BASE_URL}/characters`)

  
  const renderCard = characters.map((character) => {
    return (
      <CardContainer key={character._id} imageUrl={character.imageUrl}/>
    )
  })

  return (
    <Container>
      {renderCard}
     <ModalScreen showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default CharacterCard
```

The hook is this

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const useRequestData = (initialState, url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)

        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
        })
    
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.data)
        })
    }, [url])

    return (data)
}

export default useRequestData
```

[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Vbj.png)

[requisition return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5lHj.png)

API: https://disneyapi.dev/docs

Comment: From the error it's clear that `characters` is not an Array object. Check the return value of `useRequestData`. Can you post the documentation for this hook ?

Comment: We don't know what `useRequestData` is or what it returns.  But if `characters.map` is not a function then `characters` is not an array.  So what is it?  Your very first debugging step should be to determine exactly that.  Output `characters` to the console just before you try to use it: `console.log('characters', characters);`  When you do that, what is logged to the console just before the error?

Comment: Where does `useRequestData()` come from? If it like [this one](https://github.com/zhan006/useRequestData) you should be using `const [characters] = useRequestData....`

Comment: I added an image of the hook. I tested the character and it returns undefined.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the default value of the `characters` is undefined.
So something like `(characters || []).map..` will help I think.
For deeper look at this you can debug `useRequestData` hook, as I can't see the source of that hook from you example

Comment: It didn't work, the error remains the same.

Comment: Had `characters` been undefined, a different error would have been shown: "cannot read property map of undefined".

Comment: I added an image of the hook

Comment: Sorry, yeap you have the wrong type of 'characters' variable, The type you got does not have `.map` method